# PHP Unit test fails at creation of record

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have a test in php that fails now that I use the create method. When using this controller function online it works fine but the test fails. This is the test

```
public function testSendContactMail()
{
    $response = $this->call('POST','/contact-us',[
        'name' => '',
        'phone' => '',
        'email' => '',
        'message' => '',
        'contact'  => '',
        'help' => '$request->input()',
        'list' => '$request->input()'
    ]);

    $response->assertStatus(201);
}
```

This is the controller function being called with the route

```
public function sendMail(Request $request){
    $contact = EmailMessage::create([
        'first_name' => $request->input('firstName'),
        'last_name' => $request->input('lastName'),
        'phone_number' => $request->input('phone'),
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'message' => $request->input('message'),
        'contact_preference'  => $request->input('contact'),
        'help_you_with' => $request->input('help'),
        'email_list' => ($request->input('toList'))? true : false,
    ]);

    if($contact){
        Mail::to('test@test.com')
            ->queue(new ContactUs($contact));
        Mail::to($contact->email)
            ->queue(new ContactUs($contact));
        return Response::json([], 201); // Status code here
    }else{
        return Response::json([], 500);
    }
}
```

This is the data I pass to the controller:

```
{
    firstName: this.contactForm.firstName,
    lastName: this.contactForm.lastName,
    phone: this.contactForm.phoneNunber,
    email: this.contactForm.email,
    message: this.contactForm.message,
    help: this.contactForm.help,
    list: this.contactForm.mailingList,
    contact: this.contactForm.contact
}
```

Not sure what is going on

Comment: Wha did you do to debug this so far?

Comment: Tried looking over the request to make sure they match and tried printing out the response but It was hard to find anything useful in it since it was so long

Comment: I guess you need to track it down using dump or dd. because when you writing tests and the tests fails for a reason this means your code is not satisfying the test. if you used TDD principle then your test shouldn't fail or as I have said you should track it down maybe you have some problem in ContactUs class, because in testing usually the QUEUE_DRIVER=sync. also, you can just check the logs and see what wrong happened.